# Camera2 Api autoflash not work

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I needed to help with android camera 2 api automatic flash.
This solution works on one phone but not on the other.
I've spent a few hours searching for solutions, but I'm unsuccessful.

My takePhoto code:

```
pictureTaken = false;
    if (null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        int width = 1024;
        int height = 768;
        cv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fotak_zeleny));
        ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        if (flashMode == FLASH_AUTO) {
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        } else if (flashMode == FLASH_ON) {
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
        } else if (flashMode == FLASH_OFF) {
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
        }

        // Orientation
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        final File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        } 
etc....
```

My create camera preview code:

```
protected void createCameraPreview() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, false);

        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //The camera is already closed
                if (null == cameraDevice) {
                    return;
                }
                // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This solution work fine on my LG phone, but on alcatel not work. 
I tried a lot of ideas that are written here, unsuccessfully.

Can help me please?

Big thanks

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

You should set your selected AE_MODE for the preview request as well, and update it whenever the user switches flash modes. In addition, you need to run the precapture sequence on any devices that are higher than LEGACY level.

Changing flash mode for just the single still capture request won't work correctly, since the phone won't have the opportunity to fire a preflash to properly calculate flash power.

Take a look at [camera2basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic) for running the precapture sequence.  It always sets AE mode to AE_MODE_AUTO_FLASH if possible, but the same code will work fine for the other flash modes (though you can skip the precapture sequence if flash is set to OFF, generally, as long as focus quality is OK).

Comment: I just set FLASH_MODE_OFF for preview and it worked, though my preview is auto and shot is manual

Answer (score 0):

If you Command click on `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH`, you will see this:

- The flash may be fired during a precapture sequence

  - (triggered by {@link CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER android.control.aePrecaptureTrigger}) and
  - may be fired for captures for which the
  - {@link CaptureRequest#CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT android.control.captureIntent} field is set to STILL_CAPTURE

That means you have to trigger the the precapture sequence first before capturing the picture.

Can look at the Google's sample app here for the detailed implementation, https://github.com/google/cameraview

Answer (score 0):

I use default camera application because this camera api is different on different phones.